# How do I select the results that were inserted?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, insert

I have two tables in a SQLite database.

First table:

```
id  |  name    |  number
1   |  Paul    |  1
2   |  John    |  2
3   |  Jessica |  3
```

Second table:

```
id  |  name    |  number
1   |  Aaron   |  1
2   |  Barbara |  2
3   |  Erik    |  3
```

I do a JOIN LEFT and I insert the result in the second table, so:

First table:

```
id  |  name    |  number
1   |  Paul    |  1
2   |  John    |  2
3   |  Jessica |  3
```

Second table:

```
id  |  name    |  number
1   |  Aaron   |  1
2   |  Barbara |  2
3   |  Erik    |  3
4   |  Paul    |  1
5   |  John    |  2
6   |  Jessica |  3
```

After, in other sql statement, I select the results which were inserted in the second table ( 4 | Paul | 1; 5 | John | 2 and 6 | Jessica | 3).

Can i do this in one sql statement to get a better performance?

Thanks

Comment: Generally not - an `INSERT` and a `SELECT` are separate operations. But can you expound on the `LEFT JOIN` more? Unless this is quite simplified as an example I don't see how a join is necessary for that stage.  If we know more about the insertion process and the subsequent `SELECT`, there may be a way to know more about the inserted rows in advance and at least improve the performance of the `SELECT` query.

Comment: some other RDBMS systems like Postgres can do this using a returning clause, but MySQL hasn't implemented this feature. If you're using sqlite, you may be able to get the rowid of the inserted row, but that's about it.